# Best choice of database for my C# application

Tags: c#, database

I'm writing an application which will involve interaction with the database. The application will be used by users from the scale of 100 to 1000 and the database should be able to store up to 100,000 rows of data.

Previously I have used Microsoft Access but my users were required to install microsoft access database engine for my application to function as intended. I want my application to as light weight/portable as possible, so is there any better alternatives where users will not be required to install any third party components to run my application?

Comment: That depends very heavily upon whether this is a client-only app where they will be storing the data on their local machine, or if this is a client-server app where they will be running a local GUI that interfaces with a server elsewhere. Can you specify that requirement?

Comment: is this a client server or web based app?

Comment: As written, this question is too wide open.  Is cost a consideration?  What kind of app?  What kind of knowledge do you/your company have on database support?

Comment: It's a client based app. The database will be stored on client local machine.

Comment: You don't have to install MS Access to access a microsoft access database with C#.  You just need the OLE DB Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether the DB will be server side or client side.

If it's server side it's up to you really, I would personally go SQL Server as I know that best, or even a mySql/phpMyAdmin combo. But if it's to reside on the client machine try SQLite (just a warning though it is exactly as the name suggests, LITE, so a lot of the more complex SQL might not be supported). SQLite may be exactly what you're looking for depending on the complexity involved in your project.

ALSO: SQLite is supported on iPhone, Blackberry and Android as well. So if you wanna go mobile, no problem.

Comment: SqLite is not meant for that type of load.  He is best served using a database engine that runs as a service (SQLServer, MySql, Oracle, etc).

Comment: @tsells - Like I said, it depends on whether the DB will be stored on his server and linked to via web services etc.... Or if it has to be stored on each client machine. Having to have all your clients install SQLServer would not be a sound decision, in more ways than one. The most records I've ever stored in SQLite (on iPhone in this case) was about 45,000 rows of data, without too much hassle. 100,000 should be okay, depending of course on how much is in a row.

Comment: The Express edition (SQL Server Express) could be another way of handling it, but it's Windows only and it bloats your install immensely. I've seen plenty of apps that relied upon it for large amounts of data storage.

Comment: @PaulG IF he has 100 users I doubt he plans on having it stored locally.  Unless this is a true stand alone app (doubtful based on number of users and requirements for scaling) then he should go with a service based implementation.  SqLite is not meant for this kinda of throughput / concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

Look at mongoDB, it is an open source non relational database that has picked up popularity. Its is very fast too.

Answer (score 1):

Your application could connect to a cloud database (like SQL Azure).  That will not require any third party components and it will be accessible from anywhere/any device.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a only one database for all the users or every user has it's own database? If it will be on the server side, i would prefer SQL Servers (ex. MSSQL, MySQL). But for clients side, SQLLite would do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider if a SaaS model is relevant, in other words if you could benefit from hosting all your users' databases on the cloud and let clients access it by remote. In your scenario I would consider a SaaS model if: (1) your users need to scale up their individual database beyond the capacity of their local machine, (2) there is a need to share data between the databases of different users - or maybe this could enable good features you don't have in your system today, or (3) users find it a drag to have to run the database on their local machine, because of the resources it uses up, uptime needed, backups, etc. If any of these are sometimes true, hosting all the databases on the cloud with some sort of multi-tenancy arrangement might be a good solution and will make your application as lightweight as possible because you don't need to include a database at all.